# JS Encapsulation - IIFE vs Regular Function

Tags: javascript, encapsulation

Learning the JS [Module Pattern](https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/).

I am trying to figure out the differences between an IIFE and a regular function in this use case. It looks like the ONLY advantage of an IIFE is that my module becomes an object (since the IIFE returns immediately) so I don't need to use the call invocation/param `()` syntax on my module.

Is there any additional benefit? Consider the following code:

```
//IIFE
var HelloWorldEncapsulated = (function(){
  return {
    privateMethodEncapsulated: function () {
      console.log('ayy lmao encapsulated');
    } 
  }
})();

HelloWorldEncapsulated.privateMethodEncapsulated();

//Just a function
var HelloWorld= function(){
  return {
    privateMethod: function () {
      console.log('ayy lmao');
    } 
  }
};

HelloWorld().privateMethod();
```

Again, is there any difference between the two besides using `()` and not using it? It seems that `privateMethod` is just as hidden in the non-IIFE function as it is in the IIFE. [Code here in case you don't want to type 2 words](https://plnkr.co/edit/pDgAgADwXskI1RGRVEKv?p=preview)

Comment: Because you're not capturing any variables in the closure (in the first example), it's effectively exactly the same as the second one.

Comment: Primarily opinion-based question detected.

Comment: Oh, I remember now, all the `private` props are going to be closures iirc. Alright, I will go re-remember this all, thanks!

Comment: Actually there's no private props difference in the two things in the question (except as a side-effect of re-executing it, getting a whole new set of private props, if that's what you do).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok, thanks, I think I get it now - eventually the IIFE will have persistent private props in its closure whereas the regular function won't? Anyway, that's another question.

Comment: @VSO: The important thing here is that there is no difference in the fucntions (IIFE vs. the other). It's *when you call them* and *what you do with the result* that's different. If you want a single copy of what the function creates, with just one copy of any private data, etc., then the IIFE is the way to go. If you want your thing to be a factory, where you call it repeatedly to create discrete objects with their own private properties, don't use an IIFE, use a function you execute several times. IIFEs are not special in any way.

Comment: I think I understand close to fully now, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference in those is when you're executing your function. In your second example, if you want to call another method (or call `privateMethod` more than once), you'd have to execute it *again* (not ideal):

```
HelloWorld().privateMethod();
HelloWorld().privateMethod(); // Calls HelloWorld a second time, creating a
                              // whole new object to make the call on (bad idea)
```

...or remember the result of the first execution an dreuse it:

```
var hw = HelloWorld();
hw.privateMethod();
hw.privateMethod();
```

...at which point you're back to your first example.